# Unable to catch my errors in my react native project from my express backend

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, express-validator

I am creating a react native project mostly just to learn and I am having an issue with catching some of my error messages in the react-native side from my express server. My express server is using express-validator to do some preliminary validation. The express-validation part works as I am able to use postman to retrieve the response (i.e. 'Please enter a password with 8 characters'), but I can never get these errors to send successfully to RN. Even trying to send JSON in response to an 'error' I intentionally create seems to not allow me to catch it.

Below is the signup route, the utility function (imported from another file), and the chunk of code that I believe should be catching the error. I am not very good at asking for help, so if any additional information would benefit those willing to assist, please let me know.

**//SIGNUP ROUTE**

```
router.post(


// accrue validation checks
  '/signup',
  [body('userName', 'Please choose a username name.').not().isEmpty()],
  [
    body(
      'password',
      'Please enter a password with at least eight characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 8 }),
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    // send accrued validation checks
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(401).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

// hash password and store new user in database, then send back a JWT
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    connection.query(
      `INSERT INTO user (user_name, email, hashed_password, first_name, last_name)
      VALUES ('${req.body.userName}', '${req.body.email}', '${hash}', '${req.body.firstName}', '${req.body.lastName}')`,
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(401).json({ error: error.message });
        } else {
          let userName = req.body.userName;
          console.log(userName);
          UtilityFunctions.returnJWT(res, req.body.userName);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

}
);

**// UTILITY FUNCTION**

```
  returnJWT: (res, userName) => {
const payload = {
  user: {
    userName,
  },
};
jwt.sign(payload, secret, {}, (err, token) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send(token);
});
```

},

//**CODE IN React-Native TO CATCH ERROR**

```
const authenticate = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
  try {
    let res = await axios.post(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      userName: userName,
      password: password,
      password2: password2,
    });
    // Clears local state after successful authentication
    let token = res.data;
    dispatch(storeAuthToken(token));
    props.navigation.navigate(Dashboard);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.message, err.errors);
    if ((err.message = 'Request failed with status code 401')) {
      setError('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
    } else {
      setError('Woops! Something went wrong. Please try again.');
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setError('');
    }, 4000);
  }
```

};

Comment: Instead of username, password, password2, you have to pass data object, like ```data:{username, password, password2}```

Comment: ```axios.post(url[, data[, config]])```

Comment: Hey Muhammed, thanks for the reply but its not the passing data TO the server that is the issue. The information is posted to the database correctly. Its only the return on an error that is not happening the way I expect. I don't know that the data object in the post request would have anything to do with the try - catch block, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: the way you are passing data to server is not correct, if you are sure it is correct way, then please check in browser network tab whether your data is attached with request.

Comment: Hey Muhammed, I made the change you requested, from passing in the object individually to creating a data object and passing that in. While I'll admit it looks cleaner, it still does not solve the issue that I am facing. That data was flowing FROM React-Native TO my express backend. My issue comes from whenever I throw an error, it does not correctly flow FROM my express backend TO react-native. I appreciate the help though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, as embarrassing as this is to admit, I managed to solve my own problem. I had tried many variations of logging the response, but I did not delve deep enough. I had tried the following.

```
console.log(error)
console.log(error.errors)
console.log(error.response.errors)
console.log(reponse)
```

Turns out I just need to actually think for 2 minutes and figure out the nesting.

The errors were being passed in error.response.data.errors.

I do appreciate Muhammads help though.